# How to query by time in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What can i do to query records by the time in a date time field? And by "time," i mean the time without the date. For example, I want every record that's created at midnight of any day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Product.where("created_at like ?", "%00:00:00%")
```

Comment: it works local, but not on heroku, any idea why? It said "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown" and "HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
" (an arrow is pointing at the 'l' in 'like')

Comment: The solution you need is completely DB-dependent. I don't know your DB there. If it's PostgreSQL, try `created_at::text`.

Answer (score 4):

More like this:

```
Product.where("time(created_at) = time(?)", Time.new(2008,6,21, 24,0,0, '-00:00'))
```

EDIT

I added the timezone param to Time.new, that param should match the timezone you have your date time fields in your database.

Comment: @Andy did that answer your question?

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it didn't work for me, i used the other solution.